# Corner images do not move to corner when resizing window

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have came to a problem which i don't quite understand. I hope someone will point out to me where i made error so i can fix it.
Page is working fine on mobile phone and desktop but when i do these steps on desktop version, my top corners do not move to upper-corners automatically.

1. I manually resize window to very small (resizing is ok)
2. I click on button to make it big again (resize is ok)
3. I click on button to make it small right away and my upper-corners images don't jump to upper corners right away. If i just resize for a px in whatever direction, the corners jump to the corner.

Html images
[T-R](http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss215/reycika/page_border_corner_T-R_zpsthd6szgc.jpg)

You can see how the corners don't move to wanted position [Picture](http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss215/reycika/resize-error_zpsitcilyiq.png)

My html:

```css
/* I have another css for small devices, but it's same except instead of 32px is 21px */

body{
   font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
   background: #f0e3df url("../img/page_border_line_top.png") repeat-x left top
}

#wrapper{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   min-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   background: transparent url("../img/page_border_line_bottom.png") repeat-x left bottom;
}

#border_left{
  float:left;
  width:32px;
  height:100%;
  background: transparent url("../img/page_border_line_left.png") repeat-y right bottom;
  margin:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#border_right{
  float:right;
  width:32px;
  height:100%;
  background: transparent url("../img/page_border_line_right.png") repeat-y right bottom;
  margin:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
} 

#TL, #TR{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:auto;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
}

#BL, #BR{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="border_left">
    <img alt="corner top left" id="TL" src="img/page_border_corner_T-L.png" />
    <img alt="corner bottom left" id="BL" src="img/page_border_corner_B-L.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="border_right">
    <img alt="corner top right" id="TR" src="img/page_border_corner_T-R.png" />
    <img alt="corner bottom right" id="BR" src="img/page_border_corner_B-R.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: Please include the images that your HTML source references.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister hi thx for fast response. I added one more link to pictures, i don't have enough reputation to put pictures in my post nor to post more than two links. Is this now more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, i figured it's not even good practice what i had so I made new CSS with 3x3 grid after searching the internet a little.

Now i have only problem to tell CSS that the middle div (actual content) should stretch inside the edges.